# redirection with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

hi i have a website. in this i want to redirect on specific pages.if sobebody type http://xyz.com?a=4&b=5 in the url it should be redirect on http://xyz.com?a=10&b=22.
how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your backend script (php, ruby, asp.net) to perform the redirect. However possible in htaccess, you will be writing too many rules for the redirect cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use the `RewriteMap` directive to do what you want: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

However, I have to admit that I found it quite complicated when I tried and ended up giving in and going for a PHP based solution as suggested by @Jared. I found it more flexible and suitable to the use-case I was implementing.